# I am learning to program Windows forms apps with C# and visual studio 2010, I am past the "hello world" whats a good next step?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am learning to program Windows forms apps with C# and visual studio 2010, I am past the "hello world" whats a good next step?

Comment: Start building upon it whatever you think it's interesting, and look for tuts. This is a good way to get started IMO but don't rely only on tuts!

Comment: [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

Comment: This is not really a great question as there is no right answer.  Maybe if you were specific as to what you want to accomplish long term.  But just a side note, even though `WinForms` won't be going away any time soon, if you are learning a .NET GUI, maybe you should consider [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) instead

Comment: I'm not convinced Euler will help with WinForms :-)

Comment: Think of something simple that you can automate - e.g. design a form that takes the name of a student, her CA and Exam. After clicking Save, display the name and the Total Score in a message box - simple

Answer (score 3):

Make a text box that you can receive data from, submit that form and then display the result somewhere. Do something to make your program interactive.

Answer (score 2):

Start putting more controls on those forms, such as a temperature converter, or a simple RPN calculator.

Anything that gets you thinking about the interactions between form elements will advance you beyond `HelloWorld`.